# Add "Edit With Photoshop" To Right Click Menu

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, right-click

Is there a way to add an option "Edit with Photoshop" to the right click menu in Windows? I know I can just go to "Open With > Adobe Photoshop CS6" but that's about 3 extra steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the "context menu" and while you can edit it through the registry, it's much easier to use a tool such as [FileMenu Tools](http://dottech.org/10341/customize-your-windows-explorer-right-click-context-menu-with-filemenu-tools/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also put a shortcut in the "Send To" area in the user profile.  This is easily done by editing the "Start" menu using Windows Explorer as an Administrative user.